# Alguien sabe por que me da este error?

Tags: matlab, octave

Ejecuto mi codigo pero octave me manda este mensaje

```
error: called from
    regionprops at line 23 column 7
```

---

```
clc

clear all;

close all;

pkg load image;

im = imread('pillsetc.png');

umbral = graythresh(im);

im_bw = im2bw(im, umbral);

%%Definir un elemento estructurante que sirve como filtro -->
##existen diferentes tipos de filtro en este ejemplo se usa en forma de diamante 

se = strel('diamond', 2); %elemento estructurante

%%Operaci�n open --> 

im_o=imclose(im_bw,se);

im_c=imopen(im_o,se);

im_o1=imopen(im_c,se);

im_c1=imclose(im_o1,se);

img_bw = bwlabel(im_c1);

imshow(label2rgb(img_bw))

stats = regionprops('table',img_bw);

hold on;

for k = 1:length(propiedades,1)

  h = rectangle ("Position", stats(k).BoundingBox);

  set(h,"EdgeColor",[1, 0, 0]);

endfor
```